# Converting struct.unpack usage from python 2 to 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have some old py2 code that I used to open a binary file and read+modify a bunch of data from it. I'm now calling this from a py3 script and I've been attempting to convert it, but I'm stuck. There's this line:

`tmp = list(struct.unpack("f" * size, f.read(4 * size)))`

where `f = open(filename, 'rb')` and `size` is always 200. When I run it, I get `struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 800`. I did a print of `f.read(4 * size)` and it only gave me `b''`, which obviously isn't 800 characters long, so is that the issue?

Here's the full code for context:

```
def getVectorData(filename):
    f = open(filename,"rb")
    words = int(f.read(4)) # # of unique words
    size = int(f.read(4)) # # of dimensions
    vocab = [" "] * (words * max_w)
    M = []
    for b in range(0,words):
        a = 0
        while True:
            c = f.read(1) # reading each word character by character.
            #print(c) # this does return actual data, not just ''
            vocab[b * max_w + a] = c;
            if len(c) == 0 or c == ' ':
                break
            if (a < max_w) and vocab[b * max_w + a] != '\n':
                a += 1
        print(f.read(4 * size))
        tmp = list(struct.unpack("f"*size,f.read(4 * size)))
```

Comment: Do you realize that your code as posted does an `f.read(800)` to `print`, and then another `f.read(800)` for the bytes _after_ that to unpack? If your real code does that, it's almost certainly a problem, although maybe not the only one (or even the one you're trying to solve).

Comment: I didn't know that doing sequential `f.read(800)`s was a problem, no. When I first ran it it didn't have that print, and the error still occurs without it.

Comment: Meanwhile, this would be a lot easier to answer with a [mcve]. As far as the code does, you seem to have done a good job isolating the relevant part, but without some kind of sample data, there's still no way to debug it. (And ideally you could strip it down to a size like, say, 4 instead of 200, so it's small enough to embed as `f = io.BytesIO(b'…')` in the code.)

Comment: Every time you do a `read`, it moves the file pointer ahead by as many bytes as it reads, so those bytes are essentially used up and no longer available. (Well, unless you seek, or close and reopen the file, etc.) And, even if your real code doesn't have this line, if you've made the same mistake somewhere else, that could explain why you're trying to read from past the end of the file (which will always return `b''`) rather than from where you expected.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha. I did check and I haven't got the same mistake (doing a print with a read) elsewhere. All I know is that it worked in py2, but fails in py3; I read that in py2 doing `f.read()` returns a string, while in py3 it returns a bytes object (so `b'this'` instead of 'this'), but I'm not sure how to fix that.

Comment: That isn't a problem. A Python 3 `bytes` object is nearly the same thing as a Python 2 `str` object. (The only big difference is that when you iterate over them, you get integers rather than one-character strings.) And, more to the point, the `struct` code in Python 3 is designed specifically to work with `bytes` in exactly the same way the `struct` code in Python 2 does with `str`.

Comment: Anyway, you need to strip this down to an example that includes sample data and that works on Python 2 and demonstrates the problem on Python 3. Otherwise, nobody will be able to help you except by getting lucky with a wild guess.